# Не вызывается шаблон функции для char

Tags: c++, функции, сортировка, шаблоны-с++, char

Нужно написать шаблон функции для сортировки двумерного массива и вызвать для целочисленного, вещественного и символьного массивов. Шаблон Sort не вызывается для символьной функции c_mas - "отсутствуют экземпляры, соответствующие списку аргументов", "идентификатор с_mas не определен". Как вызвать шаблон функции для c_mas? И почему в шаблоне Sort закомментированная часть, которая должна менять ячейки местами, работала неправильно? Целочисленный массив вернулся состоящим из других цифр (только от 0 до 3), а вещественный вернулся весь состоящий из 1.1

```
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
void Sort(T* mas, int n, int m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n*m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = n * m - 1; j > i; j--)
        {
            if (mas[j] < mas[j - 1]) swap(mas[j], mas[j - 1]);
           /*{
               T tmp = mas[j];
                mas[j] - mas[j - 1];
                mas[j - 1] = tmp;
            }*/
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int const n = 4, m = 6;
    int i_mas[n][m];
    //cout << "Целочисленный массив\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            i_mas[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            cout << i_mas[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << endl;
    int const n2 = 4, m2 = 3;
    double d_mas[n2][m2];
    //cout << "Вещественный массив:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m2; j++)
        {
            d_mas[i][j] = (rand() % 10 + rand() % 10*0.1);
            cout << d_mas[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << endl;
    char c_mas[n][m];
    //cout << "Символьный массив:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            c_mas[i][j] = rand() % 26 + 97;
            cout << c_mas[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << endl;
    Sort(*i_mas, n, m);
    //cout << "\nЦелочисленный массив после сортировки:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) cout << i_mas[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    Sort(*d_mas, n2, m2);
    //cout << "\nВещественный массив после сортировки:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m2; j++)
        {
            cout << d_mas[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << endl;
    Sort(*с_mas, n, m);
    //cout << "Символьный массив после сортировки:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << c_mas[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

1. В строке `Sort(*с_mas, n, m);` у Вас присутствуют русские символы (подозреваю, что это `с`). Попробуйте переписать эту строку только с английским алфавитом.
2. 

```cpp
for (int j = n * m - 1; j > i; j--)
{
    if (mas[j] < mas[j - 1]) // swap(mas[j], mas[j - 1]);
    {
        T tmp = mas[j];
        mas[j] - mas[j - 1]; // вроде бы здесь должно быть mas[j] = mas[j-1] =/
        mas[j - 1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Что там символ русского алфавита даже и в мыслях не было.

Answer (score 0):

Вам же вчера уже писали, что нужно либо выделять память под массивы динамически, либо по-другому их объявлять в аргументах функции. И если будете выделять память динамически, то функция `Sort` будет выглядеть вот так `void Sort(T** mas, int n, int m)`, вам же нужны двумерные массивы?

Насчёт вашего второго вопроса по поводу закомментированного кода, вы меняли местами не элементы, а ссылки на внутренние массивы(подмассивы, не знаю как правильно это назвать). *И скорее всего это неопределенное поведение, но насчёт этого не уверен может, кто придет напишет более точно и пояснит.*

Comment: `идентификатор с_mas не определен` , а насчёт этого верно написал @4500zenja, у вас скорее всего просто русская **c** в `c_mas`

Comment: да, там были испробованы и способы, которые вчера подсказывали, но с русской буквой конечно не сработало. теперь вызывается без изменений в параметрах.